# How do I get Mathematica to show a number in non-exponential form?

Tags: output-formatting, number-representation

Sometimes I make a calculation in Mathematica that produces a big number, which Mathematica shows like so:

```
-1.52522*10^7
```

This is annoying to me, because I want to see the number normally, without exponential notation, something like this:

```
-15,252,264.7448716
```

How can I make Mathematica show the number normally?

Comment: Your cross posted, please delete your question SO.

Comment: @belisarius Done.

Comment: AccountingForm omits the digits after the decimal point, and also uses parentheses for negative numbers which is annoying.

Comment: @Artes `AccountingForm` shows ugly negative numbers :)

Comment: @RamRachum So your example was neither appropriate nor the question clear.

Comment: @Artes I hope I've made the example clearer now.

Comment: `AccountingForm[-15252264.7448716\`15, NumberSigns -> {"-", ""}]`  ?

Answer (score 13):

You may use for example:

```
pr[n_] := NumberForm[n, Infinity, ExponentFunction -> (Null &)]
```

so that:

```
pr[1.52522*10^7]

(* 15252200. *)
```