# Convert number to string

Tags: string-manipulation

How can I convert the number `-0.000007` to a string `-0.000007`?

I tried:

```
x = -0.000007;
ToString[x]
```

That gives an exponential output.

```
ToString[AccountingForm[N[x, 10], {10, 6}]]
```

gives the value without sign and parentheses around

```
(0.000007)
```

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/24210/36601 Is that the number style you are looking for?

Comment: yes ... great, this is a solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
x = -0.000007;

str = ToString @ AccountingForm[x, {12, 10}, NumberSigns -> {"-", ""}];

str // FullForm
```

> "-0.000007"

```
ToExpression[str] + 1
```

> 0.999993

Comment: Thank you for the solution. When I evaluate `str // FullForm` I get:  AccountingForm[-7.`*^-6,List[12,6],Rule[NumberSigns,List["-",""]]]

Comment: I made a copy mistake, see updated answer with `ToString`